# Send email one hour after a PHP script is run using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: php, email

When a user adds a video to my website, I'd like to send an email one hour after their post, alerting them that it has been uploaded and is ready for their review.

Anyway to do this using Windows Task Scheduler? The email is sent using a php file, so ideally the php file would run and then an hour after it runs is when the email is sent.

Comment: The short answer is there is not really any way to do this with Windows Task Scheduler. You want to use Queues or Cron jobs to achieve this sort of functionality

Comment: Why not send the email when the video is actually uploaded?  Why 1 hour later?

Comment: Because it currently takes about an hour for the video to finish uploading and processing.

Comment: The point still stands, why not send it when the uploading and processing is done?

Comment: An elegant solution would be to use MSMQ messaging, have the site write a message to MSMQ and then a handler that checks the message queue and sends emails for messages that are an hour old.  Oh, & you can use sql job scheduler if you have email set up in SQL & depending on your env. factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some assumptions:

- You have stored the file upload date/time in database somewhere.
- You have a PHP script that is written to read this database field and
  check if its been an hour since the upload.
- You also have a field which flag if the email has been sent for an
  upload.

Assuming the above three are true you can have a Task Scheduler entry like

`C:\Path\to\php.exe -f "C:\Path\to\send_email.php"`

If you are using older versions of Windows which does not allow you to enter commands in it but only select a program, then save this command as a `batch file` and select it from the interface

Now bear in mind if you want it to send emails after exact one hour then you will need to schedule this task to run every minute.